# Why is the icon of my script not the same?

Tags: unity-game-engine, icons

today is created a script but i noticed, that the icon isn't the same as always. [The GameManager script icon isn't the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUnhk.png)

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity has a special icon for scripts called "GameManager" specifically because scripts named "GameManager" tend to have special meaning.

It is possible to assign your own icons to scripts if you feel that you will need to quickly identify them in the project window.  (See documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/AssigningIcons.html)